# jQuery. Drag'n'Drop rows between two tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, redips.drag

I have two tables in witch I need realize Drag&Drop for table rows.

For that I used [REDIPs.drag library, like in example15 in demos](http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-row/).

Here the simplified mirror code from my project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="redips-drag-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <style>

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var redipsInit = function () {
                var rd = REDIPS.drag;
                rd.init();
                rd.hover.colorTd = '#FFCFAE';
                rd.hover.colorTr = '#9BB3DA';
                rd.hover.borderTd = '0px solid #32568E';
                rd.hover.borderTr = '0px solid #32568E';
                rd.rowDropMode = 'after';
                rd.dropMode = 'single';
                rd.event.rowMoved = function () {
                    rd.rowOpacity(rd.obj, 85);
                    rd.rowOpacity(rd.objOld, 20, 'White');
                };
                rd.event.rowDropped = function(targetRow, sourceTable, sourceRowIndex) {
                    rd.deleteObject(rd.objOld);
                };
                rd.event.rowDroppedSource = function () {
                    rd.deleteObject(rd.obj);
                    rd.rowOpacity(rd.objOld, 100);
                };
            };
            function fx() {
                redipsInit();
            };

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="fx()">
        <div id="drag">
            <p>
                <b>First table:</b>
            </p>
            <TABLE ID="TABLE1" BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" style="margin-top:15px; width:30%">
            <col style="text-align:center; width:50px; border: 0px" />
            <col style="width:20%; text-align:center;" />
            <col width="60%" />
            <col width="15%" />
                <THEAD>
                    <TH>-</TH>
                    <TH>Column 2</TH>
                    <TH>Column 3</TH>
                    <TH>Column 4</TH>
                </THEAD>
                <TBODY>
                    <TR style="height:45px;">
                        <TD class="rowhandler">
                            <div class="drag row">
                                <img src="" style="border: none;" />
                            </div>
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            1
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            One
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            00.00.0000
                        </TD>       
                    </TR>
                </TBODY>
            </TABLE>

            <br />

            <p>
                <b>Second table:</b>
            </p>
            <TABLE ID="TABLE2" BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" style="margin-top:15px; width:30%">
            <col style="text-align:center; width:50px; border: 0px" />
            <col style="width:20%; text-align:center;" />
            <col width="60%" />
            <col width="15%" />
                <THEAD>
                    <TH>-</TH>
                    <TH>Column 2</TH>
                    <TH>Column 3</TH>
                    <TH>Column 4</TH>
                </THEAD>
                <TBODY>
                    <TR style="height:45px;">
                        <TD class="rowhandler">
                            <div class="drag row">
                                <img src="" style="border: none;" />
                            </div>
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            2
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            Two
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            11.11.1111
                        </TD>       
                    </TR>
                </TBODY>
            </TABLE>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just download **redips-drag-min.js** and put it in the same folder with sample.html.

Note: Drag rows using non-existing image icon in the first column of the row.

**How I can block drop rows into or above THEAD tag?**

Answer (score 0):

[REDIPS.drag documentation](http://www.redips.net/javascript/redips-drag-documentation/) has the answer for your question.
Read it.

**EDITED:** You really don't read the documentation. Just put class=mark on all th in thead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="redips-drag-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <style>

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var redipsInit = function () {
                var rd = REDIPS.drag;
                rd.init();
                rd.hover.colorTd = '#FFCFAE';
                rd.hover.colorTr = '#9BB3DA';
                rd.hover.borderTd = '0px solid #32568E';
                rd.hover.borderTr = '0px solid #32568E';
                rd.rowDropMode = 'after';
                rd.dropMode = 'single';
                rd.event.rowMoved = function () {
                    rd.rowOpacity(rd.obj, 85);
                    rd.rowOpacity(rd.objOld, 20, 'White');
                };
                rd.event.rowDropped = function(targetRow, sourceTable, sourceRowIndex) {
                    rd.deleteObject(rd.objOld);
                };
                rd.event.rowDroppedSource = function () {
                    rd.deleteObject(rd.obj);
                    rd.rowOpacity(rd.objOld, 100);
                };
            };
            function fx() {
                redipsInit();
            };

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="fx()">
        <div id="drag">
            <p>
                <b>First table:</b>
            </p>
            <TABLE ID="TABLE1" BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" style="margin-top:15px; width:30%">
            <col style="text-align:center; width:50px; border: 0px" />
            <col style="width:20%; text-align:center;" />
            <col width="60%" />
            <col width="15%" />
                <THEAD>
                    <TH class="mark">-</TH>
                    <TH class="mark">Column 2</TH>
                    <TH class="mark">Column 3</TH>
                    <TH class="mark">Column 4</TH>
                </THEAD>
                <TBODY>
                    <TR style="height:45px;">
                        <TD class="rowhandler">
                            <div class="drag row">
                                <img src="" style="border: none;" />
                            </div>
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            1
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            One
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            00.00.0000
                        </TD>       
                    </TR>
                </TBODY>
            </TABLE>

            <br />

            <p>
                <b>Second table:</b>
            </p>
            <TABLE ID="TABLE2" BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" style="margin-top:15px; width:30%">
            <col style="text-align:center; width:50px; border: 0px" />
            <col style="width:20%; text-align:center;" />
            <col width="60%" />
            <col width="15%" />
                <THEAD>
                    <TH class="mark">-</TH>
                    <TH class="mark">Column 2</TH>
                    <TH class="mark">Column 3</TH>
                    <TH class="mark">Column 4</TH>
                </THEAD>
                <TBODY>
                    <TR style="height:45px;">
                        <TD class="rowhandler">
                            <div class="drag row">
                                <img src="" style="border: none;" />
                            </div>
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            2
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            Two
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            11.11.1111
                        </TD>       
                    </TR>
                </TBODY>
            </TABLE>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't an answer on my question. In cells I can't drop other cells if target cell have class "mark", none about rows, or ignoring drop accept if target under THEAD. I alreeady checked that

Comment: You didn't post any usable code and your english is very bad. Its hard to understand what you need. Made a better question, be more specific in your needs.

Comment: I've updated question. See small example of the problem.